# change direction in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i use "fullcalendar" and i need to change ".fc-content" direction to "rtl". when i try it, create a problem with select a cell (do not selected except left column)

you can see : http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/selectable.html .
inspect element (firebug) and change ".fc-content" direction to "rtl" to see the problem.except left column ,other cells do not seleced.

```
  .fc-content{
    direction: rtl;
  }
```

thank you

Comment: what you exactly needed

Comment: i need to use "fullcalendar" in "right-to-left languages", the "isRTL" option of "fullcalendar" only right-to-left text, but i need to table be "right-to-left" too (column ordering). @KarthickKumarGanesh

Comment: can you give an screen shot of what you need

Comment: i need this: [rtl fullcalendar](http://s13.postimg.org/t0eecrmvb/fullcalendar.png). but cells do not selected!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with fullCalendar v2.2.6.

It is fixed in v2.9.1: 
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.9.1